# Get the child element of a Custom Class in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom class `ModelWorkspace` which derives from the `Border` and  I've used it in my XAML as below:

**XAML**

```
<workspaces:ModelWorkspace x:Name="ModelWorkspace" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas x:Name="ModelWindow" Width="0" Height="0">
    </Canvas>                
</workspaces:ModelWorkspace>
```

**Custom Class**

```
public class ModelWorkspace : Border
{
}
```

Now I want to write a constructor in this custom class and somehow access the child element of this custom class which is `Canvas: ModelWindow` in this case and then add a new `Canvas` to this child element.

```
public class ModelWorkspace : Border
{
    public Canvas innerLayer { get; set; }

    public ModelWorkspace()
    {
        innerLayer = new Canvas();
        // Get the child element here and add the
        // innerLayer as its child.
    }
}
```

So the final result should look something like this:

```
<workspaces:ModelWorkspace x:Name="ModelWorkspace" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas x:Name="ModelWindow" Width="0" Height="0">
        <Canvas> // this is the inner layer we added by code.
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>                
</workspaces:ModelWorkspace>
```

**Update**:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomClass.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:customClass="clr-namespace:CustomClass"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <customClass:ModelWorkspace>
            <Canvas x:Name="ModelWindow" Width="0" Height="0">
            </Canvas>
        </customClass:ModelWorkspace>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomClass
{
    public class ModelWorkspace : Border
    {
        public Canvas innerLayer { get; set; }

        public ModelWorkspace()
        {
            innerLayer = new Canvas();

            // Add "innerLayer" to the canvas defined as the child of this ModelWorkspace.
            var childCanvas = Child as Canvas;
            if (childCanvas != null)
            {
                childCanvas.Children.Add(innerLayer);
                MessageBox.Show("This worked!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have inherited from `Border`, which further inherits from `Decorator`, you can access the child element of your control with the [`Decorator.Child`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.decorator.child.aspx) property.

```
public ModelWorkspace()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    innerLayer = new Canvas();

    // Add "innerLayer" to the canvas defined as the child of this ModelWorkspace.
    var childCanvas = Child as Canvas;
    if (childCanvas != null)
    {
        childCanvas.Children.Add(innerLayer);
    }
    // else the child is not a canvas.
}
```

Comment: Thanks SpikeX, it gives me a minor warning that I'm calling virtual member in cosntructor, `var childCanvas = Child as Canvas;` But it is not big deal. it is working.

Comment: @Vahid I believe it's because `Child` may or may not be initialized since it's virtual. If you want to remedy this, you could check if `Child != null` before continuing, but since it's your own control, you would know if `Child` was set or not via the XAML. :)

Comment: Yes, it won't be null. Thanks for the big help.

Comment: Sorry SpikeX I guess I was wrong this is not working :( I updated the question with the complete code so you can check it easily. The message inside the constructor is never executed.

Comment: Debug the application. What is `Child` set to, and what is `childCanvas` set to after the cast? Is it null? If so, then `Child` is not actually a `Canvas` for some reason.

Comment: I put all the code in the constructor into a method and executed manually in code behind after `InitializeComponent` and that worked. But in the constructor it doesn't get executed.

Comment: @Vahid That is correct. `InitializeComponent()` is what initializes a lot of the WPF objects for a window or control, so if you want to write code that uses your XAML/WPF objects, you must place it after that call. I failed to notice that in the code you posted.